# two tables with multiple joining conditions in lambda expressions

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, expression

I want to join two tables. The joining columns are column3, column4 for both the tables.

Visual Studio is throwing the following error:

> The type arguments for method
>
> 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func,
>   System.Func, System.Func)'
>
> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

My code is as follows:

```
int i = context.Table1.Where(u => u.column1 == true).Join(
    context.Table2.Where(u => u.column2.ToUpper() == "COMPLETED"),
    q => new { Column3 = q.column3, Column4 = q.column4 },
    u => new { Column3 = u.column3, Column4 = u.column4 },
    (q, u) => new { q.column1 }).Count();
```

What is wrong with this query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The query itself seems fine, but we don't know the full type of `context.TableX`.

For the Join to compile, both anonymous types defined by the `new { Column3 = q.column3, Column4 = q.column4 }` parts need to have the same property types, so that the generated anonymous types are the same. Do the entries of `Table1` and `Table2` have the same type, or may it be that their columns types don't match?

On my machine, the line

```
l1.Join(l2, 
        d => new { P = d.Column1, Q = d.Column2 }, 
        d => new { P = d.Column1, Q = d.Column2 }, 
        (d, u) => new { d.Column1 }).Count();
```

compiles fine, with `l1` and `l2` both being of type `List<Dummy>` and `Dummy` just having two integer properties.

Comment: Yes, the type of both there are same. In spite of that, the problem has come. Though I have solved it creating another column so that I can have a solution for my client.
But I eager to know what leads the query throwing error.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this some times, and the solution is simply to cast each column to the correct type:

```
int i = context.Table1.Where(u => u.column1 == true).Join(
context.Table2.Where(u => u.column2.ToUpper() == "COMPLETED"),
q => new { Column3 = (string)q.column3, Column4 = (decimal?)q.column4 },
u => new { Column3 = (string)u.column3, Column4 = (decimal?)u.column4 },
(q, u) => new { q.column1 }).Count();
```